# Is there a preposition that has to be used before "yesterday/tomorrow/today evening/morning/afternoon?

Tags: prepositions

Is there a preposition that has to be used before "yesterday/tomorrow/today evening/morning/afternoon?

Example:

- I met one of my friends yesterday evening.

Answer (score 0):

In the example you provided:

> I met one of my friends yesterday evening.

no preposition is necessary.

---

In other context(s), a preposition might be needed:

> - We met some day **before** yesterday.
> - We get ready **for** tomorrow.
> - We have to wake up early **in** the morning.